# adding kafka connect jdbc driver

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, sybase, confluent-platform

I'm trying to access a SAP Advantage DB with kafka connect using JDBC. 
I'm using the docker container, and I have added the jdbc driver Jar
FROM: http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=20&Release=19&Product=12&Platform=11

When I try to use it I get a bad URL error

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
mode=bulk
topic.prefix=adv-
connection.password=password
tasks.max=1
connection.user=admin
name=JdbcSourceConnector2
connection.url=jdbc:extendedsystems:advantage://localhost:6262/mydb
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
```

Comment: You'll want to add your other Connect configuration file

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the Database in  Dialect class of JDBC connector. Only then "advantage" URL will be identified

Please add advantage in the class and rebuild the connector . Then you will not face the above issue of Bad URL error

Comment: thanks, I don't work there anymore at that company anymore, but I'll see if I can get a copy of advantage to test it.